How to enable Nvidia nvJPEG encoder (nvjpegenc) in GStreamer
After installing GStreamer (MSVC 64-bit, runtime and developer installer) with all features and plugins enabled at the installation process on Windows 11, the Nvidia nvJPEG encoder library nvjpegenc is still not available. Via the gst-inspect-1.0 command I can find nvjpegdec being there, but not nvjpegenc. It just says No such element or plugin 'nvjpegenc'.
I also installed the CUDA toolkit, since I read somewhere this might be necessary..
Is there something I can do to enable nvjpegenc? Couldn't find any information on how to install additional plugins on Windows. Or is it just not possible?

If you are using CUDA Toolkit 10.0 or 9.0, please download the nvJPEG installer.

I downloaded cuda_12.6.2_560.94_windows.exe

Also tried now to copy the three nvJPEG files I found in CUDA to the GStreamer directories (dll, h, lib) ... didnt help
